# This is creating an infinite loop, but I don't know why

Tags: arrays, operator-overloading, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a class for an array of bits. It uses an unsigned char array and i need it to print out all the bits of the array from start to finish, but instead it just prints 0101010.... infinitely.

```
    ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const BitArray& a)  // infinite ???
    {
    int arrayelement;
    int print;
    int i = 0;
    int z = 0;
    int charsize = sizeof(unsigned char);
    os << "(";

    for (i; i < a.arraySize; i++)
    {
        arrayelement = a.barray[i];

        for (z; i < charsize; z++)
        {
            if (((arrayelement & z) == 0))
            {
                print = 0;
                os << print;
            }
            else if (((arrayelement & z) == 1))
            {
                print = 1;
                os << print;
            }
        }

    }

    os << ')';

    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your inner for loop, `i` is not increasing. Since `i` will never become greater or equal to `charsize`, it loops endlessly.

Changing `for (z; i < charsize; z++)` 
to `for (z; z < charsize; z++)`
looks to be what you want.